# Rails Checkbox to enable/disabled several fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I'm creating a Rails 3.1 app and I want add in my view a checkbox tag that I should use to enable/disable editing of many fields; I explain better: I've a model named Hardware and I've two Hardware fields named 'warranty_start' and 'warranty_end'. and this is code relative to these:

```
<div class="group">
    <%= f.label :warranty_start, t("activerecord.attributes.warehouse.warrenty_start", :default => "Inizio garanzia"), :class => :label %>
    <%= f.date_select :warranty_start, :order => [:day, :month, :year], :class => 'date_select', :start_year => Time.now.year-3, :end_year => Time.now.year + 10 %>
  </div>
  <span class="description">Data di inizio Garanzia</span>
  <div class="group">
    <%= f.label :warranty_end, t("activerecord.attributes.warehouse.warrenty_end", :default => "Fine garanzia"), :class => :label %>
    <%= f.date_select :warranty_end, :order => [:day, :month, :year], :class => 'date_select',:start_year => Time.now.year-3, :end_year => Time.now.year + 10 %>
  </div>


    <span class="description">Data di fine Garanzia</span>
```

I want a checkbox that if enabled, let user to choose a date for warranty_start and warranty_end. In witch way can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use JavaScript for that. Maybe use jQuery.

HTML:

```
<div id="warranty">
    <!-- Here you put inputs with warranty start and end -->
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#id_of_checkbox').click(function(){
    $('#warranty').css('display', ($(this).is(':checked') ? 'block' : 'none'));
});
```

In Rails you must define in model (change :column_checkbox to column name:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :warranty_start, :presence => true, :if => :warranty_want?
    validates :warranty_end, :presence => true, :if => :warranty_want?
    def warranty_want?
        warranty_checkbox == true
    end
    # rest of your model
end
```